# as400 RPGLE get UTC time in UNIX epoch format

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Still learning RPG/as400.
I need to get the current date and time in UTC in UNIX epoch format. I havent had much luck searching on how to covert a standard dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss into unix format either.
Is it possible to pull UNIX time stamps from the as400?

Comment: Isn't Unix epoch an integer representing the number of seconds since 01 Jan 1970?

Answer (score 2):

There is a always a need for things like this when you communicate with the outside world, f.e. JWT (check if token is expired).

And you can also do this without C functions:

```
**FREE

ctl-opt dftactgrp(*no) actgrp(*caller);

dcl-pr sys_getUtcOffset extproc('CEEUTCO');
  offsetHours int(10);
  offsetMinutes int(10);
  offsetSeconds float(8);
  feedback char(12) options(*omit);
end-pr;

dcl-c UNIX_EPOCH_START z'1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000';

main();
*inlr = *on;


dcl-proc main;
  dcl-s uxts int(10);
  dcl-s now timestamp;
  dcl-s offsetHours int(10);
  dcl-s offsetMinutes int(10);
  dcl-s offsetSeconds float(8);

  now = z'2020-04-15-00.00.00.000';
  sys_getUtcOffset(offsetHours : offsetMinutes : offsetSeconds : *omit);

  uxts = %diff(now : UNIX_EPOCH_START : *SECONDS) - offsetSeconds;

  // Output : 1586908800
  dsply %char(uxts);
end-proc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I really question the need for this...

But from ILE RPG, you can call C functions...this one seems to be the one you'd want...
[mktime() — Convert Local Time](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rtref/mktime.htm#mktime)

If you're not familiar with calling C functions from ILE RPG, here's a good article and even covers mktime().
[Supplementing RPG's Native Date/Time Support](https://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/rpg/supplementing-rpgs-native-datetime-support)

Note that the required prototypes and data structure definitions can be found in the "System Includes" library, QSYSINC, in the ILERPE source file (QRPGLESRC) member "time"...just

```
 /include QSYSINC/QRPGSRC,TIME
 dcl-s  myUnixTime like(time_t)
 dcl-ds myTimeDs   likeds(struct_tm)

 //note: fill in myTimeDS here
 myTimeDs.tm_min = 0;
 // and so on...
 myUnixTime = mktime(myTimeDs);
```

If the QSYSINC library isn't on your system, ask your admin to install `option 13 - System Openness Includes` of the OS (LICPGM 5770-ss1)

Last resort, you can use the below extracts..

```
 D time_t                        10I 0 template
 D struct_tm...
 D                 DS                  QUALIFIED ALIGN
 D                                     TEMPLATE
  //  int tm_sec;             /* seconds after the minute (0-61)        */
  //  int tm_min;             /* minutes after the hour (0-59)          */
  //  int tm_hour;            /* hours since midnight (0-23)            */
  //  int tm_mday;            /* day of the month (1-31)                */
  //  int tm_mon;             /* months since January (0-11)            */
  //  int tm_year;            /* years since 1900                       */
  //  int tm_wday;            /* days since Sunday (0-6)                */
  //  int tm_yday;            /* days since January 1 (0-365)           */
  //  int tm_isdst;           /* Daylight Saving Time flag              */
 D tm_sec                        10I 0
 D tm_min                        10I 0
 D tm_hour                       10I 0
 D tm_mday                       10I 0
 D tm_mon                        10I 0
 D tm_year                       10I 0
 D tm_wday                       10I 0
 D tm_yday                       10I 0
 D tm_isdst                      10I 0
 D mktime          PR                  LIKE(time_t)
 D                                     EXTPROC('mktime')
 D  time                               LIKEDS(struct_tm)
```

Comment: Thank you. I need this to pull location history of our assets. The date ranges must be in unix format and coded into the request headers.